# Angular map fields in common

Tags: angular, typescript

I am implementing a modal and I would like to map values from the `formBuilder` to a property.

This is my code:

```
submit(data?: any) {
    // THIS WORKS, BUT BAD CODE QUALITY
    this.contact.firstName = this.contactForm.value.firstName;
    this.contact.firstName = this.contactForm.value.lastName;
    this.contact.firstName = this.contactForm.value.Email;
    this.contact.firstName = this.contactForm.value.PhoneNr;

    // THIS IS WHAT I WOULD LIKE TO DO (BUT CONTACT HAS MORE FIELDS THAN CONTACTFORM) 
    // this.contact = this.contactForm.value;

    this.onSubmit.emit(data);
}
```

The problem is that the property has more fields than the `formBuilder`. Is there a way where I can map the fields that they have in common but keep the other fields of 'Contact'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this below.

```
this.contact = {...this.contact, ...this.contactForm.value};
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `spread Operator`

```
this.contact = {...this.contactForm.value};
```

Comment: That's interesting. Right now the only problem is that it completely overwrites this.contact. I would like it to only overwrite the fields that they have in common.